# Python script to loop through all files in directory, delete any that are less than 200 kB in size

Tags: python

I want to delete all files in a folder that are less than 200 kB in size.

Just want to be sure here, when i do a ls -la on my macbook, the file size says 171 or 143, I am assuming this is kb correct?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This does directory and all subdirectories:

```
import os, os.path

for root, _, files in os.walk(dirtocheck):
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
        if os.path.getsize(fullpath) < 200 * 1024:
            os.remove(fullpath)
```

Or:

```
import os, os.path

fileiter = (os.path.join(root, f)
    for root, _, files in os.walk(dirtocheck)
    for f in files)
smallfileiter = (f for f in fileiter if os.path.getsize(f) < 200 * 1024)
for small in smallfileiter:
    os.remove(small)
```

Answer (score 31):

you can also use `find`

```
find /path -type f -size -200k -delete
```

Comment: it's a question regarding python, the answer should remain in the same domain

Answer (score 28):

You could also use

```
import os    

files_in_dir = os.listdir(path_to_dir)
for file_in_dir in files_in_dir:
    #do the check you need on each file
```

Answer (score -2):

Generally `ls -la` is in bytes.

If you want it in "human readable" form, use the command `ls -alh`.