# Most efficient way to delete a file if it's below a certain size

Tags: python

What's the most efficient way to delete a file if it's less than 100k?

```
file = '/path/to/file.mov'
```

Comment: Which Python modules did you look at?

Comment: Do you actually need to do this in python, or can you make do with a combination of command line commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python script to loop through all files in directory, delete any that are less than 200 kb in size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947313/python-script-to-loop-through-all-files-in-directory-delete-any-that-are-less-t)

Comment: Command line is fine -- just looking for efficient options. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`os.path.getsize`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) (returns file size in bytes) and [`os.remove`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.remove) like that:

```
import os

file = '/path/to/file.mov'
if os.path.getsize(file) < 100 * 1024:
  os.remove(file)
```

Comment: For some reason `os.remove(file)` can't delete 0 length files under Windows 10.

Comment: above code did not work for me. I am in Ubuntu, using Spyder Anaconda, try to delete txt file less than 5k.